# Can't logout using Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, api

So I created this basic code to log in/out using Facebook. A minute ago everything worked fine, I was changing stuff and then suddenly, I couldn't logout. I stripped the code down to the pure login/out lines, but it still doesn't work. I never see the Log in link. Even if I click Log Out, I still see my e-mail, so obviously I still have access to my facebook info. 
This api is driving me crazy, only this morning getUser() always returned 0, whether I'm logged in or not, now it's the other way around - it always returns a user, even if I log out!

```
<?php
    require '../facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php'; 
    $appID = '175698905xxxxxx';
    $secret = 'cc8f99df86f7978c67xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => $appID,
      'secret' => $secret
        ));

    // Get User ID
    $user = $facebook->getUser();   
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms' => 'email,read_stream,user_birthday'));
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
    if (!$user)
    {
        echo '<p><a href='.$loginUrl.'>Log in.</a></p>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<p><a href='.$logoutUrl.'>Log out.</a></p>';  
    }
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');  
    echo $user_profile['email'];
?>
```

Update: OK, I guess the code is fine, if I try using it from a different computer, it works ok the first time, but after I log in, the logout link doesn't work again.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to know what is going on because your code is *sorta* okay.
Consider resetting your app secret, removing the app from your application list (In your test users or your profile if you don't use test users) and clearing your cache.

Also to test to see if there is nothing else going on, place in a try/catch for an API call and see if it raises an exception

```
if ($user) {
    try {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
    }
}
```

Also as Lawrence mentioned

> ... method returns the Facebook User ID of the current user, or 0 if there is no logged-in user

So instead of extra work why not just switch it around so that if $user is defined in anyway call the logout URL.

```
if ($user) {
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email,read_stream,user_birthday'));
}
```

*Notice that I am using `scope` which is the accepted way for the permissions array in the latest PHP SDK*

Answer (score 0):

@phwd 's solution is really great. I enhanced it with the following setcookie() line:

```
if ($user) {
        try {
            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) { //session was AFTER ALL invalid!
            error_log($e);
            $user = null; // we behave as if FB is logged-out (which it is actually!)
            setcookie('fbm_'.$facebook->getAppId(), '', time()-100, '/', '.yourdomain.com'); //add this also just in case, even the latest php SDK has problem sometimes clearing this cookie. Now after a page refresh the php sdk will not return a userid.
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps you out in case of further problems.

Answer (score 0):

`$logoutUrl` logouts from facebook.
To clear the retrieved data you have to clear the entire session.

```
<a href='?sessionEnd'>seesion end</a>"

if(isset($_GET['sessionEnd'])){
    session_destroy();
    setcookie('PHPSESSID',false);   
    header('Location: /');
    exit();
}
```